# passing parametr as an array doent work in NPGSQL conection

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

I am trying to pass a string array as a parameter to postgres function through NPGSQL connection using the below code in c#

```
     using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("up_getsbom", pgcon))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("market", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar, market);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("srchtype", NpgsqlDbType.Integer, srchtype);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("country", NpgsqlDbType.Array | NpgsqlDbType.Varchar, country);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("modelcode", NpgsqlDbType.Array | NpgsqlDbType.Varchar, modelcode);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("classificationcode", NpgsqlDbType.Array | NpgsqlDbType.Varchar, classification);




                NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());


            }
```

my postgresql function is like below..

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.up_getsbom(market character varying, srchtype integer, country 
         character varying[], modelcode character varying[], classificationcode character varying[])
            RETURNS TABLE(sbom_data character varying)
        LANGUAGE plpgsql
         AS $function$
         declare
          country varchar[] := country ;
         modelcode varchar[]:= modelcode;
          begin
         if srchtype=1
             then
          return query
            select distinct updated_country_name from tbl_sbom_final tsf where applicable_markets = 
    market;
    end if;
   if srchtype=2
    then  
       return query 
        select distinct model from tbl_sbom_final tsf2 where updated_country_name =any (country );
       end if;
      if srchtype=3
        then 
         return query 
          select distinct classification from tbl_sbom_final tsf2 where (updated_country_name =any 
    (country) and model =any (modelcode));
     end if;
      end;
      $function$
         ;
```

i get a result set when i call the function from script editor like this...

```
    select * from up_getsbom('Asia', 2, '{"CHINA"}', '{}', '{}')
```

but when the function is called from  NPGSQL connection from c#.... this doesnt work... Please help....

Comment: What kind of error did you get?

Comment: i dont get any error but an empty table @Abdusoli